# How to Validating a string against a list of strings in Fluent validation?

Tags: c#, .net, validation, model-view-controller, fluentvalidation

I have an email address field for which there is a client side validation of not allowing few temp domains like tempmailder.com or dispostable.com.

On the server side I have used fluent validation, for specifying the validation rules.

The temp domains which are not allowed in the web.config file as a comma separated string.

is there a way I can specify to validate the value which is entered by the user against the list of not allowed email domains.

```
RuleFor(x=>x.EMail). and something
```

Thanks

Comment: `RuleFor(x => listOfBannedDomains.Contains(GetDomainFromEmail(x.Email)) == false);`

Answer (score 6):

Well, you can implement something like this :

```
public class MyObjValidator : AbstractValidator<MyObj> {
        public MyObjValidator()
        {
            // Other rules for my object
            // .
            // .
            RuleFor(o => o.Email)
                .NotEmpty()
                .Must(BeNonBannedDomain)
                .WithMessage("Please specify a valid email address");
        }

        private bool BeNonBannedDomain(string email)
        {
            var domainName = GetDomainName(email); // a method to extract the dmain name from the email
            return !someListOfBannedDomains.Contains(domainName); // a list of all the banned domains that I need to check against.
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.